# Why isn't OpenCL finding any devices?

Tags: c, opencl

I've been messing around with OpenCL, and it seems it's not detecting that I have a device to use in my computer (which I do).

Here's the result of dxdiag:

[image]

Here is the first part of my code, where the error is being raised, checking for the number of devices available on my machine.

```
cl_platform_id platform;
cl_uint num_devices;
cl_int err;

//get first platform
err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);

if (err < 0){
    perror("Couldn't find any platforms");
    exit(1);
}

//determine number of devices: ERROR RAISED AS RESULT OF THIS
err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 1, NULL, &num_devices);

if (err < 0){
    perror("Couldn't find any devices");
    exit(1);
}
```

This is the output from this code:
[image]

And when I print the number of devices it *is* finding, with

`printf("Found %d devices", num_devices);`

It gives the same number every time:

[image]

Please let me know what other information may help in figuring this out.

Comment: Don't print an *unsigned* value with `%d`, use `%u`.  See [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: Your first platform is probably platform 0, not 1. Anyway you should check all your platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't be certain that it's not finding the devices because you haven't properly checked the return value.  There are 5 values ([more](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceIDs.html), depending on your OpenCL version) that [`clGetDeviceIDs`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceIDs.html) can return:

- `CL_SUCCESS` if the function is executed successfully.
- `CL_INVALID_PLATFORM` if platform is not a valid platform.
- `CL_INVALID_DEVICE_TYPE` if device_type is not a valid value.
- `CL_INVALID_VALUE` if num_entries is equal to zero and device_type is not NULL or if both num_devices and device_type are NULL.
- `CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND` if no OpenCL devices that matched device_type were found.

You should check your `err` value against those to be sure that `CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND` is actually the case.

---

Similarly, you should use supply the `num_platforms` value for [`clGetPlatformIDs`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetPlatformIDs.html).  It's possible that the *platform* you've selected doesn't have valid devices, but another platform does.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that both 32bit and 64bit opencl drivers are installed. If your app is 64 bit, but only a 32bit driver is installed, the device will not be found.

you can check installed devices using my app:
https://github.com/zbendefy/opencl-z/blob/master/opencl_z_1_1b.jar

Comment: Thanks that exactly was the problem.